# (mysql query performance issues) Indexing of large historical share price database

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, large-data, query-performance

this might be a trivial question for some of you but I haven't found/understood a solution to the following problem:

I have a large c 60 GB database structured the following way:

```
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date       | datetime | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| chgpct1d   | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pair       | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

The database stores the last 10 years of daily percentage changes for c 200k different pair-trades. Thus, neither date nor pair is a unique key (a combination of date + pair would be). There are c 2600 distinct date entries and c 200k distinct pairs which generate > 520 MM rows.

The following query takes c multiple minutes to return a result.

```
SELECT date, chgpct1d, pair FROM db WHERE date = '2018-12-20';
```

What can I do to speed things up?

I've read about multiple-column indices but I'm not sure if that would help in my case given that all of the WHERE-queries will only ever point to the 'date' field.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL probably does a full table scan to satisfy your query. That's like looking up a word in a dictionary that has its entries in random order: very slow.

Two things:

1. Create an index on these columns:  `(date, chgpct1d, pair)`.
2. Because the column named `date` has the `DATETIME` data type, it can potentially contain values like `2018-12-20 10:17:20`.  When you say `WHERE date = '2018-12-20'` it actually means `WHERE date = '2018-12-20 00:00:00'`. So, use this instead

   ```
   WHERE date >= '2018-12-20'
     AND date <  '2018-12-21`
   ```

That will capture all the `date` values at any time on your chosen date.

Why does this help? Because your multicolumn index starts with `date`, MySQL can do a range scan on it given the WHERE statement you have.  And, because the index contains everything needed by your query the database server doesn't have to look anywhere else, but can satisfy the query directly from the index.  That index is said to *cover* the query.

Notice that with half a gigarow in your table, creating the index will take a while. Do it overnight or something.